# Is there a way to earn resources fast?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In Metal Gear Solid 5: The Phantom Pain, is there a quick/easy method to getting resources to upgrade Mother Base and unlocking Mission 46? Can I somehow buy resources?

Comment: Extract materials containers, especially the red ones (red means stuffed to capacity). It looks like resource processing is proportional to unprocessed resources, so you don't need to worry about overloading your resource processing capabilities. (Not an answer because I'm not sure about this, and because I'm still always low on fuel.)

Comment: Yes, you can buy resources using PF points. You can buy 5000 of either Common Metal, Fuel Resources, or Biological Material for 3000 PF points. How to get those points, however, I don't know.

Comment: @Nolonar How do you specifically buy them? Edit: It's under PF Grade

Comment: You get PF points by participating in what is basically a fantasy football league for your PF. In other words the game virtually competes your PFs against other PFs, and then gives you PF points based on your "performance" and gives you a ranking as well. People are not completely sure how it works yet; it seems like the virtual battles occur daily and then award you points based on that, but for some people these virtual battles may or may not actually happen. Maybe you need to reach a certain grade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there's no way to get resources very quickly, but there are steps you can take to ensure you're getting as much as possible.

- Get your base development level up as much as you can, by recruiting staff, building extra base development platforms (on your FOB too). The higher your level the faster the timer that processes materials.
- Maintain a big buffer of unprocessed materials. The more unprocessed materials you have the more will get processed each time (it caps at 2500, except for minor metal at 1250 and precious metal at 250). If you're getting less than these totals each time, try obtaining some more containers.
- Online and offline unprocessed resources are totalled and processed separately, on different timers (by mother base and FOB respectively). So the point above applies for both, keep both your online and offline material levels high for the best yield. (you can see the break down on the resources menu, online resources have a globe next to the number)

  - Offline resources can be obtained from containers in the main game, there are multiple farming guides online for obtaining these quickly.
  - Online resources can only be obtained from FOBs. The best way I've found is scouting for level 1 base development platforms, ideally with low level staff and no added security. Beware until they're processed online resources can be stolen by opponents so a well guarded FOB is also a good idea.
- Constantly keep the maximum amount of teams out on deployment missions. If there are no missions available with worthwhile rewards, do them anyway as others with better rewards will cycle in once they're complete. Some have up to 20,000 processed materials as a reward.
- Check your PF screen, once a week (I think on Sundays- for me at least) points will be awarded for that weeks PF battles. These points can be spent on resources.

Other than that you'll have to get materials yourself, either by traveling around the map on free roam collecting them. Or by doing multiple FOB invasions and try getting to the goal as fast as you can (check the potential rewards before you go in). Defending FOBs can be a decent source too but you can't actively trigger these.

Answer (score 2):

People underestimate the Base Development platform in their FOB. They have a BUNCH of unprocessed materials you can take (usually). If you do it stealthy, they won't know that you hit them.