# Move online resources to offline resources

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

So I have a lot of online resources, but not a lot of offline resources. I want to upgrade the mother base platforms, but I do not have enough offline resources.

Is there any way to *transfer* online materials to the offline materials quanta?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I do not believe there is way to transfer materials from online to offline mother base.

I will look for a definitive source on this and post it when/if I find one.

I would suggest something along the lines of [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237052/is-there-a-way-to-earn-resources-fast) and try to quickly gather some needed resources (it also points to farming guides).

Comment: So let's say that instead of expanding motherbase I expand my FOBs. Will this allow me to process materials faster?

Comment: @Arete, don't quote me on this, but I'm pretty sure they simply behave independently. If you improve you FOB, it only affects FOB performance. If you improve mother base, it only affects mother base.